# Serde serialize_seq with unknown len

Tags: rust, serde

The documentation for [`serialize_seq`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/trait.Serializer.html#tymethod.serialize_seq) states

> Begin to serialize a variably sized sequence. This call must be followed by zero or more calls to serialize_element, then a call to end.

> The argument is the number of elements in the sequence, **which may or may not be computable before the sequence is iterated**. Some serializers only support sequences whose length is known up front.

I want to serialize a sequence whose length is unknown before iterating over the sequence.

The trivial example they give is:

```
use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeSeq};

impl<T> Serialize for Vec<T>
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(self.len()))?;
        for element in self {
            seq.serialize_element(element)?;
        }
        seq.end()
    }
}
```

How can I modify the code above to support a length which is not computable before the sequence is iterated?

Maybe I have misunderstood the documentation, but I would expect something similar to this to work:

```
use serde::ser::{Serialize, Serializer, SerializeSeq};

impl<T> Serialize for Vec<T>
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut lazy_len = 0
        let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(lazy_len))?;
        for element in self {
            lazy_len += 2;
            seq.serialize_element(element)?;
        }
        seq.end()
    }
}
```

Which would give twice the length of the sequence.

Comment: I'd assume that you can simply pass `None`  to `serialize_seq` if you don't know the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length paramater is an `Option<usize>` because maybe you have one and maybe you don't. You don't have one, so use `None` instead of `Some`.

```
let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(None)?;
```

As the note says, some serializers require a length and others don't.
Serializers will use the value that you pass to `serialize_seq` to (for example) allocate a buffer *immediately*. They get better performance by doing this once and then serializing each element into that memory. Extending the length with each item would not be at all beneficial since they will need to extend the buffer each time too, which is exactly what they'll do if you pass `None` for the length.

This should work fine with Json, but some other more efficient formats like Bincode might refuse to serialize without it. In particular, some encoding formats will serialize the length as part of the format before the values.

> Maybe I have misunderstood the documentation, but I would expect something similar to this to work:
>
> ```
> ...
> let mut lazy_len = 0
> let mut seq = serializer.serialize_seq(Some(lazy_len))?;
> for element in self {
>     lazy_len += 2;
>     seq.serialize_element(element)?;
> }
> ...
> ```

Integers are `Copy` types, so `serializer.serialize_seq(Some(lazy_len))` just copies the value of `lazy_len` and mutating `lazy_len` afterwards will have no effect.